# Zombie/Mocha browser.wait(...) method doesn't execute.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

Let's get straight to the point.

Here is a piece of code I'm using which should test the web app (which at the moment only shows `<p>Welcome!</p>`)

```
var app = require('../app');
var assert = require('assert');
var Browser = require('zombie');

describe('home page', function() {
    var browser, server;

    before(function() {
        server = app.listen(3000);
        browser = new Browser({site: 'http://localhost:3000', debug: true});
    });

    it('should show welcome', function(done) {

    // Wait until page is loaded
        function pageLoaded(window) {
            console.log('4');
            return window.document.querySelector(".container");
        }
        console.log('1');
        browser.visit("/");
        console.log('2');
        browser.wait(pageLoaded, function() {
            console.log('3');
            assert.ok(browser.success);
            assert.equal(browser.text('p'), 'Welcomexxx!');
            console.log(browser.html());
        });
        done();
    });

    after(function(done) {
        server.close(done);
    }); 
});
```

This test should not pass as I'm checking for Welcomexxx! not Welcome!. However it always passes regardless of what I test for.
As You can see I added some console outputs to the code to see whats happening. To my surprise neither 3 nor 4 shows in the console. This basically means that the wait function does not execute.

Here is the expected output for a non-failed test:

```
home page
✓ should show welcome
GET / 200 5ms - 15b
1 passing (63ms)
```

And this is my output for the above test:

```
home page
1
Zombie: Opened window http://localhost:3000/  //zombie debug line
2
✓ should show welcome 
1 passing (22ms)
```

As You can see there is also no "get" statement in the output. Also zombie seems to work in general, as browser.visit shows console output indicating that something happened.

Can anyone shed some light on why this happens? I'm capable of running the app with foreman start or node app and I can see in my browser that everything is working fine (in theory).

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I am seeing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that the call to done() should be in the callback handler to browser.wait()

```
it('should show welcome', function(done){
  ....
  browser.wait(pageLoaded, function(){
     ...
     assert( ... );
     done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You has to deal with zombie with callback function or in promise like below example:

```
browser.visit("/").then(function(){
    assert.ok(browser.success);
    assert.equal(browser.text('p'), 'Welcomexxx!');
    console.log(browser.html());
}).then(done, done);
```

Comment: right. And I dont think you have to wait for .container to load. (done() can be called after console.log() as well)